# Zooming with UIScrollView does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, zooming

So guys, The picture appears on View, the UIView is EmbedIn with ScrollView, Outlets are fine, the image appears but nothing happens when I try to zoom, I will be thankfull to any suggestions, or a sample event with Buttons + and - or slider if that will work.
I have made everything I've found over the internet and it does not work, here is my code:

```
class TakenPhotoPreviewViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewOutlet: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewOutlet: UIImageView!
var takenImage: UIImage = UIImage()
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageViewOutlet.image = takenImage
    picker.delegate = self
    scrollViewOutlet.delegate = self
    setForZoom()
```

where the methode setForZoom is

```
    func setForZoom () {
    imageViewOutlet.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: takenImage.size)
    scrollViewOutlet.addSubview(imageViewOutlet)
    scrollViewOutlet.contentSize = takenImage.size
    scrollViewOutlet.clipsToBounds = false
    let scrollViewFrame = scrollViewOutlet.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollViewOutlet.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollViewOutlet.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    scrollViewOutlet.minimumZoomScale = minScale;

    scrollViewOutlet.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
    scrollViewOutlet.zoomScale = minScale;
```

I also have the:

```
private func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    return imageViewOutlet

}
```

and even

```
 func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {

}
```

cause somebody had issues because this was not written....
Please do somebody know why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this piece of code from your application and try it should work. As of now you are restricting the ScrollView Content size with the Image size.

```
scrollViewOutlet.contentSize = takenImage.size
```

Comment: made it and still no changes...(((

Comment: are you using any hard coded width and height constraints in your storyboard?

Comment: just Builder Interface Constraints

Answer (score 0):

The issue possibly is the `minScale`, you set the `zoomScale` of `scrollView` to `minScale`. There is an issue with `minScale`, it cannot be changed, so you can't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue solved ?????Try to delete this line of Code.

```
scrollViewOutlet.zoomScale = minScale
```

by the way you should pay attention to the name of variable .